# how do I do this action using linq?

Tags: c#, linq

`busLineStation` is of type: `IEnumerable<object1>` and `dl.ConsecutivesStations()` is of type: `IEnumerable<object2>`

```
foreach (var item in busLineStation)
{
    foreach (var item2 in dl.ConsecutivesStations())
    {
        if (item.BusStationKey == item2.StationCodeOne)
            item.BusStationKeyNext = item2.StationCodeTwo;
        if (item.BusStationKey == item2.StationCodeTwo)
            item.BusStationKeyPrevious = item2.StationCodeOne;
    }
}
```

Comment: LINQ is a query language, it doesn't update anything. You can use LINQ to filter the list and return only the items where `BusStationKey` has one of two values. You can flatten nested iterations with `SelectMany`

Answer (score 0):

Using LINQ is not always an improvement, especially when you are modifying data - it is designed only for querying data.

Here is an implementation that queries the data with LINQ and then modifies it - I think it is hard to understand, complicated, and it will run slower:

```
foreach (var bs1s2c1c2 in busLineStation.SelectMany(b => dl.ConsecutivesStations().Select(d => (b, b.BusStationKey, d.StationCodeOne, d.StationCodeTwo)))
                                       .Select(bks1s2 => (bks1s2.b, bks1s2.StationCodeOne, bks1s2.StationCodeTwo, c1: bks1s2.BusStationKey == bks1s2.StationCodeOne, c2: bks1s2.BusStationKey == bks1s2.StationCodeTwo))
                                       .Where(bs1s2c1c2 => bs1s2c1c2.c1 || bs1s2c1c2.c2)) {
    if (bs1s2c1c2.c1)
        bs1s2c1c2.b.BusStationKeyNext = bs1s2c1c2.StationCodeTwo;
    if (bs1s2c1c2.c2)
        bs1s2c1c2.b.BusStationKeyPrevious = bs1s2c1c2.StationCodeOne;
}
```

NOTE: I use a `ValueTuple` to cache the values and test results so I don't access or test twice, but at the expense of an extra method call and lambda call, so it probably isn't faster.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to suggest a totally different structure. Rather than going through the station stops and then searching through the entire route for the next and previous stops, why not make one walk through the stations in order and set prev/next as you go?

If you're sure the stations are in order already you can skip the `OrderBy()` part of course.

```
StationObject previousStation = null;
foreach (var currentStation in busLineStations.OrderBy(st => st.AscendingKeyProperty))
{
  currentStation.BusStationKeyPrevious = previousStation.Code;
  if (previousStation != null) previousStation.BusStationKeyNext = currentStation.Code;
  previousStation = currentStation;
}
```

Comment: There is no standard `ForEach` method on the result of an `OrderBy`... also, I would recommend `foreach` over `List<T>.ForEach` anyway.

Comment: Comment accepted. Thanks. Also I agree with your remark in your solution: "Using LINQ is not always an improvement."

Answer (score 0):

I would agree with the others that Linq makes this less readable.

Also the .ToList() can be taken out if it is a List<> as well as an IEnumerable<>

```
    busLineStation.ToList().ForEach(item => dl.ConsecutivesStations().ToList().ForEach(item2 => {
        if (item.BusStationKey == item2.StationCodeOne) item.BusStationKeyNext = item2.StationCodeTwo;
        if (item.BusStationKey == item2.StationCodeTwo) item.BusStationKeyPrevious = item2.StationCodeOne;
    }));
```